# Move a Simulated Quadcopter in a straight line

Tags: control, quadcopter, movement

I'm trying to move a quadcopter in a simulator from (x0, y0) to (x, y) in a straight line at a constant speed. The simulator takes x and y inputs in m/s. Altitude as an input is a constant value in meters.

I found the following [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448163/how-to-calculate-velocity-from-speed-current-location-and-destination-point) below which works relatively well but the quadcopter veers off the straight line course slightly. These values are calculated every time step.

Given a constant speed **s**, initial position **(x0,y0)**, and final position **(x,y)**

Distance **d** is calculated as

$$ d = \sqrt{(x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2}  $$

Vectors calculated as
$$ Vx = \frac{s}{d}(x - x0)  $$
$$ Vy = \frac{s}{d}(y - y0)  $$

Is there a better way to calculate these inputs or should I implement some kind of PID / Cross track controller to get the quadcopter to stay moving in as straight a line as possible?

Comment: shouldn't it be x, y, z ?

Comment: z (altitude) is a constant input in this simulation in meters above take off and does not vary. I only care about the x and y movement

Comment: Smells like integration errors adding up causing the veering off.